# Fullcalendar eventDrop change background color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using latest fullcalendar and was wondering if someone could show to change "background color" of the dropped event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the CSS.

If you are using the latest Fullcalendar [2.3.0], there is a CSS file called  `fullcalendar.css` --- edit line #52 :
`background: #bce8f1;
 opacity: .3;
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);`

just change the background to the color you want.

[when you click a day, FC adds an element to the DOM with class `fc-highlight-skeleton`, among the HTML inside it, an element with a class `fc-highlight`.]

Answer (score -1):

try this in the calendar config and see what you can do.

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log(ui);  // is likely to have the parent as the day/square you dropped onto.
}
```

if not: then try finding the TD via the date object inside the event:

```
var newDate = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$('td').find("[data-date='" + newDate + "']");  //this seems to only get the header.
```

Other method would be to utilize the jsEvent to find the location/dom object where the event was dropped. Which is beyond what I know off the top of my head. but shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: this answer is absolutely irrelevant.